# How to appropriately reduce data size or take a representative sample from it?

Tags: sample-size, resampling, mathematical-statistics

I have a spreadsheet file with around 150,000 pairs (x,y). I wish to work with a smaller file, i.e., with less data, so my exploratory analysis is faster.

What is the appropriate way of resampling, or working (one time only) with this data, so I can obtain a smaller amount of pairs, loosing the "least possible" amount of information or reliability, statistically speaking.

Comment: The right way to do this is to load it into software like R or Python and work with the entire data set. It sounds like a big number, but 300,000 points is not that many. Does something prevent you from using either of those (free!) pieces of software?

Comment: I understand this is desirable, in fact I plan to do this later (learn R). Nonetheless, me and my team don't have that specific knowledge so far, and we have relied on "office" to do our exploratory analysis. In any case, I still wish to know what would be the way to compress any large data (say then 1,000,000,000 pairs), so as not to loose that much reliability and so as to obtain the same statistics (mean, etc.). Today we just cluster rounded data, without knowing this is the best way.

Comment: There’s no way to assure yourself of getting the same statistics that you would get from the entire data set. The way you (probably) get close is by taking a large random sample.

Comment: Currently, all we can advise is simple random sampling. If you could elaborate what kind of analyses / estimates you are interested in, and what kind of data this is, then a more detailed answer might be possible. Even then, likely the answer will be "take as much as you can, as randomly as you can"

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with exploratory analysis on big data

- any analysis that shows individual data points (eg a scatterplot) gets harder to understand
- computations get slow

With 150,000 you shouldn't really be having the second problem, but you *will* have the first problem.  With 150,000,000 points you might have both problems.

The second problem can be solved quite well by sampling.  You can begin by taking a simple random sample. If you need to explore in more detail in a small subpopulation (left-handed avocado farmers, say) you might use the whole data set for that subpopulation, or a sample from just that subpopulation.

For the first problem, you can either work with a random sample (often called "thinning") or with some way of aggregating points.  Two useful general-purpose ways to aggregate points in a scatterplot are [hexagonal binning](https://datavizproject.com/data-type/hexagonal-binning/) and [overplotting with partial transparency](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/03/04/how-to-use-transparency-to-overcome-overplotting.html).  The former makes individual outliers more visible; the latter makes them less  visible.

There's a book [Graphics of Large Datasets: Visualising a Million](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/425571.Graphics_of_Large_Datasets) that discusses approaches to data viz when data sets are too big to look at each point individually.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it's worth, SAS defaults to 2,000 as a sample size in it's Graph Explore nodes.  I know that this often produces graphs that are not representative in different ways.  (SAS is top-of-the line data mining software.)

If you want a random sample in Excel, add a new column, put =rand() in the first cell, copy the cell down to the bottom; select all the data (all rows/columns), sort on the new column (direction doesn't matter), and select how ever many rows you want from the top going down.

I can't imagine trying to do exploratory analysis with Excel.  Maybe there are functions I'm not aware of.  How is it easier to find the standard deviation of 1,000 rows rather than the whole set?  It's the same number of key strokes.

I would work with the whole data set.